# Tinymce - How to hook before or after live shortcodes rendering?

Tags: shortcode, javascript, plugin-tinymce

When the edit post page loads in WordPress admin, I launch a js process which alters the TinyMCE editor’s contents.

Recently I've come across the WordPress [live shortcode previews](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/shortcodes/tinymce-enhanced-shortcodes/) which break my code, because they too alter TinyMCE editor’s contents. This enhanced shortcodes uses the *wp.mce.views* api recently introduced and refactored on WP 4.2. Here more [details about last changes](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/04/23/tinymce-views-api-improvements/).

Is there way to hook my process **before** (or **after**) WordPress live shortcode previews rendering?

Answer (score 1):

Well, yes, you can do that:

```
//replace live edited content to display html
editor.on('BeforeSetcontent', function(event){
    event.content = tinymce_to_html( event.content );
});

//Transform your html content to raw content
editor.on('GetContent', function(event){
    event.content = html_to_tinymce( event.content );
});
```

Let's explain that:

Under the hood, tinymce use a plain-text editor to store content, use in forms, etc etc. But what you see is an HTML wrapper, reading the content of the textarea to set up an HTML view. If you insert special content (like a shortcode), insert the plain text shortcode, and use `tinymce_to_html` to deduce from it the corresponding HTML.

I don't remember exactly why (I've wrote this piece of code a long time ago) but `html_to_tinymce` should do the exact inverse than `tinymce_to_html`, and is important to keep your content clean when switching back & forth with plain text editor or saving it to your database.

Hope it helps, & cheers